# Solaris 10: handle gracefully ENOBUFS error when changing socket buffer

Tags: c, sockets, unix, solaris, portability

I have stumbled on a peculiar difference between Solaris 10 sockets and other Linux/*NIX sockets. Example:

```
int temp1, rc;
temp1 = 16*1024*1024;  /* from config, a value greater than system limit */
rc = setsockopt( sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &temp1, sizeof(temp1);
```

The code above will have `rc == 0` on all systems - Linux, HP-UX and AIX - except the Solaris 10. Other systems silently truncate supplied value to the allowed maximum. Solaris 10 *rightfully* fails with the `errno == ENOBUFS` indicating the configuration error.

After some deliberation, it was decided that since the particular application is critical instead of failing it should continue working as gracefully as possible:

1. Produce a warning in the log file about configuration mismatch (easy, add a check with `getsockopt()`) and
2. Try to set the maximum buffer size (to get whatever performance possible).

The #2 is were I have stuck. On all non-Solaris systems I do not need to do anything: the sockets already do it for me.

But on Solaris I'm at loss what to do. I have implemented some trivial dichotomy around `(setsockopt(...) == -1 && errno == ENOBUFS)` condition to find the max buffer size, but it looks ugly. (Neither I have a context to save the results of lookup: the search would have to be repeated for every connection with such bad configuration. Global variables are problematic since the code is inside a shared library and it is used from MT application.)

Is there any better way on Solaris 10 to detect max allowed buffer size using sockets API?

Is there any way to tell Solaris' sockets API to truncate the value like other systems do it?

Comment: Haven't used solaris for a long time - can you get tcp_max_buf out of /dev/tcp?  Otherwise some hackery with "ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_max_buf" and passing it into the pgm somehow.

Comment: Yeah... If OpenSolaris is any relevant, then [it seems to be impossible](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/ident?v=OPENSOLARIS;im=bigexcerpts;i=tcps_max_buf): tcps_max_buf is only read, but never used as function return or written into a variable. The [underlying `tcps_propinfo_tbl`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/search?v=OPENSOLARIS&im=bigexcerpts&string=tcps_propinfo_tbl) is accessed only as a whole too.

Comment: It's rather ironical for a (ex-)system programmer to find himself being a victim of a strictly compliant interface...

Comment: Well the problem is really that there doesn't appear to be a way to get the info you need to work with the compliant interface.  Looking at this a little further it seems you were not the first to encounter this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to a Solaris 10 system at the moment, but according to the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2724/chapter4-1/index.html), you can use the `ndd` utility to query (and set) the configured buffer size maximums for TCP and UDP:

```
$ ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_max_buf
$ ndd -get /dev/udp udp_max_buf
```

I'm not aware of a C API, but maybe what `ndd` uses is exposed?

Comment: I have `truss`-ed it and it goes to `/dev/tcp` and then fires couple of STREAMS specific `ioctl()` calls: I_CANPUT and I_STR. And the I_STR is apparently used to send a message to a stream module. And that is were POSIX ends - and something totally Solaris specific and under-documented starts (failed to find any documentation).

Comment: The [source code here shows](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/common/inet/ip/ip_if.c?v=OPENSOLARIS;im=bigexcerpts#L8820) that it is not a public interface. E.g. `mod_prop_info_t` isn't even declared under `/usr/include`. At the moment seems to be not doable.